# Spring Kubernetes Probes: How to implement multi-component probes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

## Scenario

I want to use the native Spring Boot mechanism to implement the Kubernetes readiness and liveness probes. The official sources state that the application's availability states should be changed by publishing events, e.g.

```java
AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(this.eventPublisher, this, ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC);
```

Spring will then make sure to reflect this in the `/readiness` endpoint.

Now let's suppose I have an application with multiple components that can influence readiness. Using only this suggested event mechanism the following scenario would not work:

1. Component A publishes `REFUSING_TRAFFIC` --> The application should become unready
2. Component B publishes `REFUSING_TRAFFIC` --> The application is still unready
3. Component A publishes `ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC` --> The application should still be unready because component B is still not ready

But in the current implementation there is only one global state so once component A publishes `ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC` the application would become ready again (even though component B did not publish `ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC` yet).

## My possible ideas

I have the following two ideas how to achieve what I want:

1. Override the endpoints (e.g. with a health group) and implement HealthContributors for every component that should influence readiness or liveness
2. Build a custom "availability monitor" which is responsible for publishing those events. Then implement custom events (e.g. a `ComponentAvailabilityChangeEvent`) which are similar to the Spring events but report availability for a specific component in the application. Once one component is unavailable, the custom monitor will publish the corresponding Spring-native event and once all components are available again, the monitor will take care to publish the global availability event.

Basically idea 1 is ignoring the build-in Spring mechanism and would break the possibility to e.g. use the `ApplicationAvailability` to get the application's state, so I think this may not be an option.

Idea 2 sounds like the best way to me but I feel like I'd implement something that Spring should be able to do natively and like I'd replicate a lot of already-present behaviour (e.g. that custom `ComponentAvailabilityChangeEvent` would be an almost-copy of the Spring-native `AvailabilityChangeEvent`).

## Question

**tl;dr:** Am I missing something? Does Spring already offer what I want and is there a clean way to implement these probes using Spring's built-in functionality but with the possibility to influence the availability on a component basis? Or do I really have to implement this logic on my own?

Comment: Each component should be separately monitored. Kubernetes monitors a pod and will restart. Packing may components into the same pod then trying to tell Kubernetes about the health of some, but not other, components does not make sense. When it comes to signaling the health of the entire system then that is not something to be delegated to kubernetes. An application service can be written to judge the health of the system and it can have its own health check endpoint so that kubernetes will keep it running.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I am well aware of how K8S probes work. My question was how to implement multi-component probes using Spring. I do not talk about different microservices but rather about things like: a database connection service, a cache connection service, a batch processing service limited by compute resources, all in the same application. This example is fictional but there are situations where the overall application state depends on many components. That is what this question is all about.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the clarification. So either the system needs restarting, or not. The HC is about the pod. It’s not a logging endpoint to observe what is the cause of the pod needing to restart. Simply log the health of the components to the normal log, and return to kubernetes whether it needs to restart the pod. Don’t overload the kubernetes health check point with “other logging concerns”. Hope that helps.

Comment: So for example one of my components might need a database resource and another access to Redis. Either can log the problem and return “down”. So one, or many, things can be checked by Spring. I found this question when googling how to emit “down” and it was pretty clear how I could have three things that checked three different resources and independently report “down”.